# How to map an Option to a String for formatting while providing an &'static str as a default?

Tags: rust

I have a function that returns an `Option<>` result. I would like to print it with a fallback like this:

```rust
println!("Result: {}", result.map_or("not found", |r| r.to_string()));
```

Unfortunately, this way I either:

- get a `&'static str` vs `String` type error,
- or get a "does not live long enough" if I do `&r.to_string()`,
- or have to convert `"not found"` to a `String` which is ugly and seems very unnecessary.

Is there a way to do this conversion while keeping the default value an `&'static str`?

Comment: What is `result`? I guess a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) or a [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) – if that's the case, what are its generic parameters (`T`, and also `E` if it is a `Result`)?

Comment: @sk_pleasant-EliasHolzmann Judging from the title of the question, it's an `Option`.

Comment: @sk_pleasant-EliasHolzmann it's an `Option`, updated the question. The generic parameters are not really important here, I believe.

Comment: I'd personally also consider `match result { Some(r) => println!(...), None => println!("Result not found") };`, which at least seems readable and easy to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a combination of `Option::as_ref` and `map_or`, the trick is to borrow the owned `Option<String>` with `as_ref`:

```rust
println!(
    "Result: {}",
    result.as_ref().map_or("not found", String::as_str)
);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28f6054d822fcaadd820d388e005192a)

As per the comments, in case is a generic type, use `map` to transform it to a String first (allocating it), then same process as above:

```rust
result
    .map(|f| foo_to_string(&f))
    .as_ref()
    .map_or("not found", String::as_str)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f72fb8a2217c6ec5577efe2a7c1031e1)

Comment: It looks like this only works when result is an `Option<String>`, otherwise there's no storage on the stack for the `map` ourcome. E.g. try the same with `struct Foo;`, `fn foo_to_string(foo: &Foo) -> String { "foo".to_string() }` and 
`let result = Some(Foo)`

Comment: @Fixpoint, you need to transform to a &str, you would have to transform your `Some(Foo)` to `Some(String)` in a previous step for that, since you need to allocate the String.

Comment: Thanks, the `map().as_ref().map_or()` solution works!

Answer (score 0):

I not sure to understand well. You want do this?

```
fn main()
{
    let resutl: Option<&'static str> = Some("test 1");
    println!("{:?}", resutl.map_or("8".into(), |r| r));
    
    let resutl: Option<String> = Some(String::from("test 2"));
    println!("{:?}", resutl.map_or("8".into(), |r| r));
    
    let resutl: Option<&str> = Some("test 3");
    println!("{:?}", resutl.map_or("8".into(), |r| r));   
}
```